# Reactjs useEffect to check whether there has been a change to an object's property's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a form that triggers a change in context each time there is a change to any input in the form. The form write to an object, which is then passed to the context. The context object looks like this

```
let form = {
    trialExperationDate: trialExperationDate,
    nextUserDate: nextUserDate,
    linkText: copyText,
    postalCode: formPostal,
    phone: formPhone,
    email: formEmail,
    pwRef: formPwRef
};
```

Where initially each property value is `''`. In my component, I want to watch as the object changes through the context API, and increase a `count` variable if any of the fields `!== ''`

My code looks like this.

```
const [context] = useContext(FormContext);
let numChange = 0;

function isNotEmptyObject(o) {
    Object.keys(o).every(function(x) {
        if(o[x]!==''||o[x]!==null || o[x] !== undefined) {
            numChange += 1
        }
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    isNotEmptyObject(context)
}, [context]);
```

The problem is, `numchange` always stays at 0.  Why? I have confirmed the object in the context is being updated.

Comment: Where are you calling `setContext`?

Comment: In another component. But i console.log the context in the active component to make sure that the context is updating, which it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a function from React.useEffect(), it will call that function on unmount. If you want it to fire on first mount and context changes, remove the return.

Comment: I tried that, no difference, but i will modify my question to reflect that point. thanks

Comment: Also, I believe `numChange` is being set to 0 on every render because of `let numChange = 0;` inside of the component.

Comment: I would give `numChange` a _state_ variable. `const [numChange, setNumChange] = React.useState(0)

Comment: Interesting thing is, now any time a change is made to any property in the object, the count is increased by 1, even though i'd like it to only count objects properties that have a value other than '' once... any thoughts?

Comment: Well isn't that what your function is doing? Based on the logic of the function everytime a value is updated the numChange will increment